# Possible to pass argument for Express app.use()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have this code which works

```
import express from 'express';

const port = 8080;
const app = express();

function auth(req, res, next) {
   const token = req.headers['authorization']?.split(' ')[1];
   if (token == null) res.sendStatus(401);
   token === 'example=' ? next() : res.sendStatus(403);
}

app.use(auth);

app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

But since the Bearer token is here hard coded to `example=` I would must rather have something like this

```
function auth(req, res, next, hardcodedToken) {
   const token = req.headers['authorization']?.split(' ')[1];
   if (token == null) res.sendStatus(401);
   token === hardcodedToken ? next() : res.sendStatus(403);
}

app.use(auth((hardcodedToken = 'example=')));
```

Where I here get the error

```
ReferenceError: hardcodedToken is not defined
```

**Question**

Does anyone know if it is possible to somehow pass an `hardcodedToken` variable to the `auth()` function?

I am willing to switch to TypeScript if needed.

Comment: The standard approach is to write a curried function, i.e. a function which takes one parameter for the token and then returns the middleware function as a closure.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks a lot. That did the trick =) I used this howto. https://tsmx.net/express-middleware-function-with-custom-parameters/